# Regex getting the first backslash

Tags: regex

I got this string:

`use \blahblah\file`

I need to get `use \` using a regex. For now I got, `\suse` but I can't figure out how to get the first  backslash. Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the below regex to get the chars upto the first `\`(including \ )

```
^[^\\]*\\
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/oU4qI3/2)

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks! will accept this as the answer in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 2):

```
^.*?\\
```

Try this.    See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/hQ1rP0/35

Answer (score 1):

you need to get `use \`, then use `use \`. remember we need to escape characters with special meaning in regular expressions